# stresslinux hanging on boot at "NMI watchdog enabled, takes one hw-pmu counter. #3"

Tags: hardware, central-processing-unit, hangs

I have a Gigabyte `GA-z170N-WIFI` (32GB memory in two 16GB modules) board that refuses to boot, When booting to real media (I.e. `Ubuntu 18 live install CD` or it's installed OS on SDD) it freezes at various points. Sometimes a kernel panic, sometimes it hangs...and it has even hung while working in the CMOS setup.

The mainboard was just replaced, but the it has the same problems as before it was replaced.

I managed to get it to boot to and run `memtest` ...which reported no errors.

The only consistent error I get is when I try to boot to `stresslinux_64bit_11.4` - where it consistently hangs at the message...

```
NMI watchdog enabled, takes one hw-pmu counter.
#3
```

[image: Screenshot]

Attempting to variations of text only knoppix either results in hangs, or kernel panics.

`boot: knoppix 0` = hangs
`boot: knoppix 1` = hangs
`boot: knoppix acpi=off` = kernel panic
`boot: knoppix acpi=off noapic nolapic` = kernel panic
`boot: knoppix acpi=off noapic nolapic pci=bios` = kernel panic

**Is it safe to say this is a bad CPU?**

Answer (score 0):

In our case, it was a bad processor. Replacing the CPU resolved the issue. Posting here for other's reference.